# Layout method using concrete retaining wall block for angled wall

Tags: concrete-block, retaining-wall

I am planning to use the rectangular 12x4 retaining wall blocks as below

[image]

http://www.lowes.com/pd_357656-215-30732___?productId=3722166

This is because we like the design of this better than using trapezoid shape (not available locally for Tranquil color and special order is too expensive).

Now this block is good for 90 degree edges only.  For example:

[image]

How do I lay them out in below shape and angle? **Without cutting the 4-in concrete?**

Or do people leave the gaps in the front wider as it's getting closer to the corner like that?

I am open to any creative idea for that corner. I was thinking about creating a small square-looking seating column using 3x4 of the blocks to "mask" the adjustment in angle and gaps.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to cutting block, you don't need to cut it (but cutting a score can be helpful). Using a rock hammer (and perhaps a chisel) to break the rock is the way it's done.

The method for shaping rocks is kind of simple, but a video is a better way to describe it... so here's a few youtube videos about shaping rocks.

[Flagstone (good info)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cA1Lta0iBhA)

[Rock hammer (more like what you're working with)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxz7oTygzfA)

[With a chisel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=er-MkuDVOl4)

Otherwise (if you are adamantly opposed to breaking or shaping stone), you could build a form and pour a concrete joint (like in the shape of a Y). If that's the plan, I would probably start with this, then lay the rock.

Also, a suggestion to make it look a little better might be to make an [exposed aggregate](http://www.dcs-ks.com/product_images/Exposed_aggregate_finishes_for_decorative_concrete.pdf) joint. There are several ways to accomplish that, but it's not really relevant here.

Comment: I am also thinking about building stair step in that Y corner. So basically from ground level up to the 2-ft high ground, then 3-ft high ground. I still don't know how to lay that one out (until I see some pictures).